# Напомните название функции в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, методы

Когда-то листая вк, видел статью с интересными функциями и методами в питоне, и там была функция, позволяющая выводить строку символ за символом с определённым интервалом времени. Если кто знает, скажите как она называлась. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не думаю, что такое существует во встроенных библиотеках, но .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432478/python-print-to-one-line-with-time-delay-between-prints

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю правильно я вас понял, но в Python есть встроенный модуль time, с функцbей sleep().
Не знаю что вы имели под "символ за символом", но это можно уже реализовать со списком.

```
from time import sleep

string = "Hello, World!" # Например классика: )

for i in list(string):
    """ sleep останавливает выполнение программы,
    на число заданное в качестве аргумента этой функции """

    sleep(1)
    print(i)
```